# HTML Elements not updated

Tags: python, element

I am trying to retreive an HTML Table from a website to save it in a csv file via a Python script.
The number of records (rows) displayed on the HTML Page is 10.
On the same HTML page there is a button to display the next 10 records (rows).

I have no issue to retreive the fisrt 10 records but when my python scirpt calls for the next 10 records, it appearing well on the HMTL but returning me the 1st 10 records in the csv...
If I reload the URL, the table is displaying the first 10 Records...so I can not use reload..

Any idea?

Tried to reload but not working

```
table1=soup.find('table', id='pageLayout_projectTeamMembersGridView_gridView')
headers = []
for i in table1.find_all('th'):
  title = i.text.strip()
  headers.append(title)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)
for row in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]:
  data = row.find_all('td')
  row_data = [td.text for td in data]
  length = len(df)
  df.loc[length] = row_data
print(df)
df.to_csv('Export.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you use and if possible the page you're scraping. It's hard to help without knowing how you are doing things, what libraries you use, etc.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I can not add the link to the HTML page I am trying to scrape
I have added all possible librairies (selenium, pandas, requests BeautifulSoup)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I find the error in my code.

I used :

```
response = requests.get(driver.current_url, verify=False)
soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

instead of:

```
response = requests.get(driver.current_url, verify=False)
soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```